# MySql - Can I add a label to a table and retrieve using sql query

Tags: mysql, label, metadata

I have a requirement to provide a REST endpoint to create/delete tables for a privileged user.

When user makes a request to create table 'xyz', I create table with prefix "user_" and return response saying
'user_xyz' is created.
This way I know what tables are candidates for deletion when a request is made.

But I wish to create table "xyz" as requested by user and would like to add  some label like "deletable"  so that I can 
query to find if a table can be deleted.

One option is adding a comment for table and but I have to query information_schema. Comment does not sound very correct.
Can this problem be solved using any other approach when I use MySql database.

Comment: Keep track of table meta data in a table?

Comment: yes, but I do not know how to add custom metadata and track it.

Comment: Users who create are not different mysql users though, right?

Comment: @Nae Need to explain bit more: User "X" calls service "ABC" endpoint. Service verify user "X" if he belongs to privileged group and if so, service apply a DDL in mysql using its own credentials. MySql has no knowledge of user "X".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have much other options other than the one you suggest,

- prefixing/suffixing table name
- use table comment
- create meta table with `UserId`(has the advantage of foreign keys)
  and `TableName` fields (has the disadvantage of integrating the table
  name with the actual very table as it can change without this
  metatable being updated)
- create separate schema for each user

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I was trying to explore all feasible options.